# Not able to print global variables

Tags: python, scope, global

I am not able to print the final statement after the function is called. I have tried other solutions from here, but can't seem to get `read_size`/`clock_rate` to be truly global.

```
def get_config():
    global clock_rate
    global read_size
    role = input("Will the Sync Link be used as downlink or uplink? Type \"downlink\"
                 "for downlink, \"uplink\" for uplink: ")
    if role == "downlink":
        clock_rate = 10240 # Convolutional encoding always disabled when sending to EDU
        print("Configured for downlink mode... Clock rate =",clock_rate,"bits per second.")
    if role == "uplink":
        CE_enabled = input("Is convolutional encoding enabled on the EDU? "
                           "1 is enabled, 0 is disabled: ")
        if CE_enabled == 1:
            read_size = 512 # When convolutional encoding is enabled, the EDU receives
                            # a 512 byte CADU frame.
            print(read_size)
            clock_rate = 20480
        if CE_enabled == 0:
            read_size = 256 # When convolutional encoding is disabled, the EDU receives
                            # a 256 byte CADU frame.
            clock_rate = 10240
        else:
            print("Invalid input")

get_config()
print("Initiating transmit/receive... Read size =", read_size,
      "bytes. Clock rate =", clock_rate, "bits per second.")
```

Comment: You would need to define `clock_rate` and `read_size` outside of the scope of the function. Why not just have your fuction return `read_size` and `clock_rate` instead?

Comment: I've tried defining the variables outside of the function, and I still can't get read_size to work. I could do that but it would involve me rewriting a lot more functions.

Comment: I would highly recommend rewriting a lot more functions

Comment: The execution of your function may or may not assign values to the two variables — so you need to ensure they exist and have some default value before calling it if you are going to refer to their values after calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to declare the clock rate and read_size variables before you modify their scope with the global keyword so you can change them.

You also need an elif CE_enabled==0 otherwise you always get invalid input if you input 1.

See below:

```
clock_rate=None
read_size = None

def get_config():
    global clock_rate
    global read_size
    role = input("Will the Sync Link be used as downlink or uplink? Type \"downlink\" for downlink, \"uplink\" for uplink: ")
    if role == "downlink":
        clock_rate = 10240 # Convolutional encoding always disabled when sending to EDU
        print("Configured for downlink mode... Clock rate =",clock_rate,"bits per second.")
    if role == "uplink":   
        CE_enabled = int(input("Is convolutional encoding enabled on the EDU? 1 is enabled, 0 is disabled: "))
        if CE_enabled == 1:
            read_size = 512 # When convolutional encoding is enabled, the EDU receives a 512 byte CADU frame
            print("Read size:", read_size)
            clock_rate = 20480
        elif CE_enabled == 0:
            read_size = 256 # When convolutional encoding is disabled, the EDU receives a 256 byte CADU frame
            clock_rate = 10240
        else:
            print("Invalid input")

get_config()

print("Initiating transmit/receive... Read size =",read_size,"bytes. Clock rate =",clock_rate,"bits per second.")
```

Comment: This is simply not true, see my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I used this and it worked. With your original code, I had an error with the API I was using but after putting clock_rate = None and read_size = None in get_config() I fixed it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Even ignoring the dependence on global variables, you aren't defining `clock_rate` and `read_size` in all possible cases. Do something like the following:

```
def get_config():
    clock_rate = None
    read_size = None
    role = input("Role?")
    if role == "uplink":
        clock_rate = 10240
    elif role == "downlink":
        ce_enabled = input("Convolutional encoding enabled?")
        if ce_enabled == "0":
            read_size = 256
            clock_rate = 10240
        elif ce_enabled == "1":
            read_size = 512
            clock_rate = 20480
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid response for convolutional encoding")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid role")
    return clock_rate, read_size


clock_rate, read_size = get_config()

print("Initiating transmit/receive... Read size =",read_size,"bytes. Clock rate =",clock_rate,"bits per second.")
```

Instead of raising an error in each case, you could provide default values (other than the previously assigned `None`) to each variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put this as an answer instead of a comment to stop any confusion from happening. To use global variables, you do **NOT** have to have initialized them in the global scope. The following code will work perfectly:

```
def some_function():
    global some_global
    some_global = "Hello, world!"

some_function()
print(some_global)
```

Globals do **not** have to be initialized in the outer scope. Instead, they can be defined in any scope at any time. The only constraint is: they must be **defined before accessed**. This is what's wrong with your code.

In the 'downlink' mode, your function does not define `read_size` and in the 'uplink' mode, you are comparing the input against `0` and `1`, which are integers and therefore those expressions will never result in `True`. This means, the `else` block is reached that tells the user the input is invalid. In this case, neither `read_size` nor `clock_rate` will be defined before the final print statement.